# Open PDF using C#-- Windows 8 Store Application

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I want to be able to open a PDF using the native Windows Reader Application when a user clicks on a button. So far I am able to use the following code to successfully open files that end with the (.PNG) extension. However, when I let the link to open the (.PDF) file I get the following error.

```
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

The file destination is correct.

Here is my code:

```
 private async void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Path to the file in the app package to launch
        string imageFile = @"Data\Healthcare-Flyer.pdf";

        var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);

        if (file != null)
        {
            // Set the option to show the picker
            var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
            options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;

            // Launch the retrieved file
            bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
            if (success)
            {
                // File launched
            }
            else
            {
                // File launch failed
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Could not find file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? Did you check the file really existed?

Comment: The error occurs on                                                 var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile); And I added the pdf to the folder by going to Add ->Existing Item. I am able to open the PDF in reader by double clicking it in the actual folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add PDF document in project, you have to change it's build action.

- Right click on PDF document.
- Click on properties.
- Change **Build Action** from **None** to **Content**